# Create vector by given distibution of values

Tags: r, vector, concatenation

Let's say I have a vector `a = (1,3,4)`.
I want to create new vector with integer numbers in range `[1,length(a)]`. But the `i`-th number should appear `a[i]` times.

For the vector `a` I want to get:

`(1,2,2,2,3,3,3,3)`

Would you explain me how to implement this operation without several messy concatenations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try `rep`

```
rep(seq_along(a), a)
#[1] 1 2 2 2 3 3 3 3
```

#### data

```
a <- c(1,3,4)
```